# Node.js button onclick function not work

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, onclick

I'm making a website using node.js.
I want to show "Hello World" when the button is clicked.
But it doesn't work properly.
this is my code.

```
http = require('http');
var onRequest = function(req, res){

    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html;charset=utf-8'});

    res.write('<script language="JavaScript">');
    res.write('function func(btn){ alert("Hello World"); }')
    res.write('</script>');

    res.write('<button ');
    res.write('name="btn1" onclick="func(btn1)" style="height:60px;width:60px"> button ');
    res.write('</button>');

    res.end();

};

var server = http.createServer(onRequest);
server.listen(port, ip);
```

This is the resource in Google Chrome:

```
<body>

    <script language="JavaScript">
        function func(btn){ alert("Hello World)"}
    </script>

    <button name="btn1" onclick="func(btn1)" style="height:60px;width:60px"> button</button>

</body>
```

The website shows the button successfully.
But it doesn't show "Hello World" when I click the button. Why?

Comment: Is there any error in your browser console

Comment: Please show us what you have tried and the errors you get with your attempts. Please also read this page to learn how to write a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you share the generated html.... in browser > view source

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: btn1 is not defined

Comment: You'll have to define btn1 or pass it as a string, e.g. `res.write('name="btn1" onclick="func(\'btn1\')" style="height:60px;width:60px"> button ');`

Comment: @FirasDurri How to define btn1 ?

Comment: Like `var btn1 = null`. Also as you explore node.js, you may want to look into expressjs.com